# Calculate driving distance between two points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, latitude-longitude

I want to measure the distance by road between two places provided the latitude and longitude of the places.

My JavaScript/Java based custom application is going to be used by offline users.

I think Google map API can't be used in this case. I need free service. arcgis provide this facility??

Any help or guide will be appreciated..

Comment: Hey, did you find the answer to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you assuming you have the latitude and longitude for both points:

```js
var rad = function(x) {
  return x * Math.PI / 180;
};

var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
  var R = 6371; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
  var dLat = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
  var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());
  var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) *
    Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c;
  return parseInt(d); // returns the distance in km
};
```

Comment: is this driving distance and can we find multiple distance between two points/latlong???

Comment: This returns the distance between two points on the map, not the driving distance, the direct route. There's only one distance between two points, there can't be multiple. Of course, if you change the route there is probably a new distance.

Comment: by multiple distance i mean multiple route to reach to destination from origin/source location..